# Hide on-screen menu bar android from code

Tags: android, menu, hide

Is there a way to hide on-screen menu bar in an android app from code?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cbs7rbac07rs5ks/Screenshot%202014-01-24%2014.24.48.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If your app runs on a device without a dedicated Menu button, the
>   system decides whether to add the action overflow to the navigation
>   bar based on which API levels you declare to support in the 
>   manifest element. The logic boils down to:
>
> - If you set either minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion to 11 or higher,
>     the system will not add the legacy overflow button.
> - Otherwise, the system will add the legacy overflow button when running
>     on Android 3.0 or higher.
>
> The only exception is that if you set minSdkVersion to 10 or lower,
>   set targetSdkVersion to 11, 12, or 13, and you do not use ActionBar,
>   the system will add the legacy overflow button when running your app
>   on a handset with Android 4.0 or higher.

Here's blog post from android devs on the subject: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html